# Changing word "welcome" to uppercase from the input string

Tags: c

I want to convert the case of word "welcome" from the given string.
All occurrences should have been changed.
What I have tried is below code,

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "ctype.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  printf("Enter the sentence you need to display via app:\n");
  char sentence[100];
  char word[10] = {"welcome"};

  scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);

  getchar();
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (sentence," ,.-");

  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    if (strcmp(pch,word) == 0) {
      while(*pch != '\0'){
        *pch = toupper(*pch);

      }
    }
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL," ,.-");
  }

  printf("%s\n", sentence);
  return 0;
}

/*
Output: 
Enter the sentence you need to display via app:
welcome here welcome there

*/
```

The program takes forever and doesn't work as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: C or C++? The solution could be *very* different depending on language.

Comment: According to the input the output should be
"WELCOME here WELCOME there".

Comment: Preferably C. I have assignment in C.

Comment: Then please don't add unrelated language tags. Only add *relevant* tags.

Comment: `while(*pch != '\0'){
        *pch = toupper(*pch);

      }` : infinite loop

Comment: As for your problem, please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stepping though your code in a debugger would have shown the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: Shouldn't stdio.h and ctype.h be insinde < > instead of " "?

Comment: you have to increase your pointer position, otherwise the `while` loop tries to uppercase the same character for ever

Comment: Worth noting that strtok may change the original string.

Comment: So use strstr to pick out instances of "welcome", then toupper() to tunr to "WELCOME"

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);` --> `scanf("%[^\n]", sentence);` This does not cause problems, but the trailing `s` is meaningless. The conversion specifier is `%[]` for scansets, and `%s` for strings.

Comment: [mcve]-ify this, please and thank you.

Comment: @VladDinev that's about the only thing that is *right*, `#include "stdio.h"` must fall back to `#include <stdio.h>` if not found otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues in your program:

- The syntax for standard include files in `#include <stdio.h>`, using `<` and `>` instead of `"`.
- You should define `word` as a pointer: `const char *word = "welcome";` or an array without a length to let the compiler compute it for you: `char word[] = "welcome";`.
- The syntax for `scanf` character ranges is `%[^\n]`, without a trailing `s`.  You should specify the limit as `%99[^\n]`.
- `scanf()` will fail if you enter an empty line. You should test the return value to avoid undefined behavior upon failure to read.
- It would be safer to use `fgets()` to read a line of input.
- You do not increment `pch` in the loop, hence the infinite loop taking for ever to execute.
- `toupper` must not be passed a naked `char`, you must convert the `char` to `unsigned char` to avoid potential negative values that produce undefined behavior.
- `strtok` has modified the `sentence`, you printing it will only print the first word (along with any preceding separators).

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char sentence[100];
    char word[] = "welcome";

    printf("Enter the sentence you need to display via app:\n");
    if (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin)) {
        char *pch = strtok(sentence, " ,.-");

        while (pch != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(pch, word) == 0) {
                char *p;
                for (p = pch; *p != '\0'; p++) {
                    *p = toupper((unsigned char)*p);
                }
            }
            printf("%s ", pch);
            pch = strtok(NULL," ,.-");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for pointing out errors.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you are missing to increase pointer for your string. In the example below, I'm using temporary variable here for updating entire string. `ptr` variable can then later be used for printing purpose.

```
if (strcmp(pch,word) == 0) {
    char *tmp = pch;
    while (*tmp != '\0'){
        *tmp= toupper(*tmp);
        tmp++; //Increase pointer
    }
}
```